# Ardunio IDE ESP32 with EthernetENC lib and SSLClient stops printing after2 prints

Tags: arduino, esp32

I am working with esp32-s3-mini and ENC28J60 chip and its quite unstable when connecting servers.
i am connecting currently to HTTPS and every 3rd client.println is crushing with error message:

```
(SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(m_update_engine): Error writing to m_client
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(m_update_engine): 0
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(connected): Not connected because write error is set
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(m_print_ssl_error): SSL_CLIENT_WRITE_FAIL
((SSLClient)(SSL_WARN)(m_run_until): Terminating with write error: 
((SSLClient)(SSL_WARN)(m_run_until): 4
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(write): Failed while waiting for the engine to enter BR_SSL_SENDAPP
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(write): Cannot operate if the write error is not reset: 
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(m_print_ssl_error): SSL_CLIENT_WRITE_FAIL
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(write): Cannot operate if the write error is not reset: 
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(m_print_ssl_error): SSL_CLIENT_WRITE_FAIL
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(write): Cannot operate if the write error is not reset: 
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(m_print_ssl_error): SSL_CLIENT_WRITE_FAIL
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(write): Cannot operate if the write error is not reset: 
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(m_print_ssl_error): SSL_CLIENT_WRITE_FAIL
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(write): Cannot operate if the write error is not reset: 
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(m_print_ssl_error): SSL_CLIENT_WRITE_FAIL
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(write): Cannot operate if the write error is not reset: 
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(m_print_ssl_error): SSL_CLIENT_WRITE_FAIL
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(write): Cannot operate if the write error is not reset: 
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(m_print_ssl_error): SSL_CLIENT_WRITE_FAIL
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(write): Cannot operate if the write error is not reset: 
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(m_print_ssl_error): SSL_CLIENT_WRITE_FAIL
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(write): Cannot operate if the write error is not reset: 
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(m_print_ssl_error): SSL_CLIENT_WRITE_FAIL
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(write): Cannot operate if the write error is not reset: 
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(m_print_ssl_error): SSL_CLIENT_WRITE_FAIL
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(write): Cannot operate if the write error is not reset: 
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(m_print_ssl_error): SSL_CLIENT_WRITE_FAIL
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(write): Cannot operate if the write error is not reset: 
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(m_print_ssl_error): SSL_CLIENT_WRITE_FAIL
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(write): Cannot operate if the write error is not reset: 
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(m_print_ssl_error): SSL_CLIENT_WRITE_FAIL
((SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(available): Cannot operate if the write error is not reset: 
(SSLClient)(SSL_ERROR)(m_print_ssl_error): SSL_CLIENT_WRITE_FAIL
```

first thought there is not enough space in SSLClient library for buffer, because my payload is around 2160 bytes but its not the case.
i tried to send less bytes in payload but no success.
i've seen there were some similar problems with ethernet.h before but can find the solution.

would very much appreciate any suggestions.

1. less bytes in payload.
2. bigger buffer in SSLClient